# How to run selenium in google app engine/cloud?

Tags: google-app-engine, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I would like to conduct selenium scripts remotely in the cloud or online and have been told that google app engine is one possibility.

Any help would be appreciated to how to run scripts on google app engine or on the cloud.

Any other ideas how to run scripts online would also be welcome.

Comment: Take a look at [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/products/compute-engine) -- that gives you a virtual Linux system compared to App Engine's virtual web server.

Comment: thanks for the pointer phillip.

Comment: It can't be a duplicate of that question, because that was asked 2 years later...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Google App Engine is not a realistic possibility for this because it does not support creating threads and it does not support native code. Browsers need both.

Answer (score 2):

Google earlier didn't provide any functionality to support custom based App Engine, it was very much sandboxed which was restricting multitude possibilities of the App Engine. But now it has been provided by Google - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/.

With this functionality Alex has posted a solution - [Python Headless Browser for GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384062/python-headless-browser-for-gae/51427118#51427118)