# What' s the better choice Google vs. Amazon Cloud Services

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud, web-hosting, google-cloud-endpoints

AMAZON VS GOOGLE

Compared to the prices and features and service
what platform should i go for if i want to host a small sql db some small apps webservice and a small storage?

What are the main differences between them?....

Has anybody experience with the these services and would like to share some Information ....

Everything is welcome!

Comment: See a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/q/21812867/1382251 (the answer to which might give you a few insights)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you've used the word "small" 3 times, I will venture to say that, in my opinion, GAE is the best fit.  Small apps remain inside the free quota on GAE, and you can't beat $0 a far as price goes.  Also, GAE handles more of the messy, time-consuming backend tasks.  I doubt you want to spend much time maintaining or setting up a "small" app, so having to deal with fewer of these tasks is beneficial.  I have some small apps on GAE which I have not even touched for a couple of years.  Time is money.