# Where can I deploy a Flask application which uses selenium at the back?

Tags: python, selenium, google-app-engine, flask

I have built a flask web application which executes python selenium script at the back and returns a response after scraping a web page.

I am now trying to deploy or host this web application on a server, preferably on google cloud. But google app engine does not support running selenium webdriver as mentioned here:
[How do I run Selenium tests with Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28564668/how-do-i-run-selenium-tests-with-google-app-engine)

Has anyone deployed a similar application or maybe just a selenium script to any of the cloud service providers?

Edit:
This is not a duplicate questions, Kindly read it carefully and avoid marking it as duplicate. Thanks.

Comment: Any cloud compute will work, e.g. Amazon EC2, Google Compute Engine, ... Choose one and deploy your Flask app as documented in the linked question.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384062/python-headless-browser-for-gae