# Taking a Screenshot for a given URL on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have been trying to take a screenshot of given URL using pyppeteer & FAST in Python. But after many attempts and fixing various errors, I managed to get it installed as an App Engine.

I am using python 3.10 and entry point for my app engine is

```
gunicorn main:app --timeout 540
```

But after looking at the logs, every time, the code seems to break at the time of launch of browser. I did try providing executable path, no-sandbox arguments, but the application keeps on failing with Browser terminated with "BrowserError: Browser closed unexpectedly:" error.

For taking screenshot, few other options were also evaluated like html2image, but that seems to require Chrome executable and not chrome driver.

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't 'install browsers' on GAE Standard (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28575892/15211203) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19940165/15211203) response)

It's the same reason why you can't run Selenium in GAE standard.

You can do this on [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run)

Comment: I did try with cloud run too, it fails with "No such file or directory: '/home/.local/share/pyppeteer/local-chromium/" error. Chrome driver related libraries were included in Dockerfile.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://nocommandline.com/blog/how-to-use-headless-firefox-on-cloud-run/) blog article we have for Cloud Run & Selenium. It might help you out

Comment: Thanks. Passed executablePath for pyppeteer it worked.