# Can Selenium be used on Google App Engine now?

Tags: google-app-engine, selenium-chromedriver, python-3.7

I am trying to run Selenium on Google App Engine. I have seen a lot of comments from years ago saying that you can't. The I found this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-headless-chrome-support-in-cloud-functions-and-app-engine) saying that headless Chrome is now available on GAE. The post has been written after the other comments that said that you can't use selenium on GAE so I gave it a try.

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

After deploying the code to gae I got this error:

```
ages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start      stdin=PIPE)    File "/opt/python3.7/lib/
python3.7/subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__      restore_signals, start_new_session)    File "/opt/pyth
on3.7/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1522, in _execute_child      raise child_exception_type(errno_num,
 err_msg, err_filename)  FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'
```

Am I doing something wrong or did I misunderstand the linked post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided is for the Node.js runtime. It might not be available in python yet.

I was able to get it working in python on App Engine Flex by doing the following

[Python Headless Browser for GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384062/python-headless-browser-for-gae/51427118#51427118)

For your specific error I had to edit the docker file to download the webdriver